# How do i create a function to convert a binary tree to a tuple?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

i came across this question where i was tasked to convert a tuple into binary tree and then convert binary tree back to tuple and return both tree and tuple. i was able to convert the tuple into the tree but i failed to create a function to do the reverse. i am just a begineer trying learn data structures.

the parse_tuple function here is used to parse over a tuple to create a binarytree which works fine.

please help me fix my tree_to_tuple function. any insights or tips to fix the logic would be great.

thanks

```
#used for creating binary tree
class TreeNode:
    
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
```

```
#used to parse over the tuple to create a bianry tree
def parse_tuple(data):
    
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 3:
        
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
        
    elif data is None:
        node = None
    
    else:
        node = TreeNode(data)
    
    return node
```

```
#doesnt work
def tree_to_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeNode) and node.left is not None and node.right is not None:
        node_mid = node.key
        node_left = tree_to_tuple(node.left)
        node_right = tree_to_tuple(node.right)
    
    elif node.left is None:
        node_left = None
        
    else:
        node_right = None
        
    return (node_left, node_mid, node_right)
```

```
tree_tuple = ((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8)))

tree2 = parse_tuple(tree_tuple)

tree_tuple2 = (1, 2, 3)
tree = parse_tuple(tree_tuple2)
print(tree_to_tuple(tree2))
```

and this is the error i am getting if i try to use tree_to_tuple

File "main.py", line 45, in tree_to_tuple
return (node_left, node_mid, node_right)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'node_left' referenced before assignment.

Comment: Well, you're always returning `(node_left, node_mid, node_right)`, but if you went through the `elif` or the `else` branches, then they will not have been defined. In the `elif` branch you only define `node_left` and forget about node_mid and node_right, and in the `else` branch you only define node_right and forget about node_mid and node_left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close but your tests are a bit messy.

Here is a patch:

```py
def tree_to_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeNode):

        #  special case if the tree has no left and no right sub-tree
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            return node.key

        return (
            tree_to_tuple(node.left),
            node.key,
            tree_to_tuple(node.right)
        )
    raise ValueError('this is not a tree')

tree_tuple = ((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8)))

tree2 = parse_tuple(tree_tuple)

tree_tuple2 = (1, 2, 3)
tree = parse_tuple(tree_tuple2)
print(tree_to_tuple(tree2))
```

Output:

```
((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8)))
```

Comment: thank you very much for this solution                                      ```

Comment: @ShivaKharbanda you're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

```
# class for creating binary tree (that has key(node), left(node), right(node)) 
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


# instead of linking nodes one by one, we can represent nodes in the form of tuple
# and we can use recursion technique to automate linking process.  
  
def parse_tuple(data):

    # check if the parameter passed is of type tuple and it's length is 3 (left node, key, right node)
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 3:
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
    
    # if it is the leaf node(last node) and it is also == None, then assign node = None
    elif data is None:
        node = None
    
    # if it is a leaf node(last node) and not != to None, then assign node = current value
    else:
        node = TreeNode(data)
    
    return node


def tree_to_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeNode):
        # check if left and right node are equal to None if so, then it means it has no child nodes
        # and simply just return key node
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            return node.key
        
        # use recursion to iterate through each sub tree and get the left , key and right nodes
        return (
            tree_to_tuple(node.left),
            node.key,
            tree_to_tuple(node.right)
        )
    # else simply return node
    else:
        return node

    
tree_tuple = ((1,3,None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8)))
tree2 = parse_tuple(tree_tuple)
print(tree_to_tuple(tree2))


Output
 ((1, 3, None), 2, ((None, 3, 4), 5, (6, 7, 8)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here's a piece of code I have written that works for me.

```
def tree_to_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeNode):

        if node.left is not None and node.right is not None:
            node_mid = node.key
            node_left = tree_to_tuple(node.left)
            node_right = tree_to_tuple(node.right)

            return (node_left, node_mid, node_right)

        elif node.left is None and node.right is None:
            return node.key

        elif node.left is None and node.right is not None:
            node_mid = node.key
            node_right = tree_to_tuple(node.right)
            node_left = None

            return (node_left, node_mid, node_right)

        elif node.left is not None and node.right is None:
            node_mid = node.key
            node_right = None
            node_left = tree_to_tuple(node.left)

            return (node_left, node_mid, node_right)

    else:
        print("It's not a tree")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
def tree_to_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeNode):
       return(tree_to_tuple(node.left), node.key, tree_to_tuple(node.right))
    else:return node
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**This is works for me**

```
def tree_to_tuple(node):
    if isinstance(node, TreeNode):
        if node.left is None and node.right is None:
            return node.key;
    else: return node;
    return (tree_to_tuple(node.left), node.key, tree_to_tuple(node.right));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code worked for me :

```
def tree_to_tuple(node):

if node is None:
    return None 
if node.left is None and node.right is None:
    return node.key


treeTuple = tree_to_tuple(node.left),node.key,tree_to_tuple(node.right)

return treeTuple
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can see why your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help].